# Having trouble with basic JSON in Unity and C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I was using a JSON file to make a list of my inventory items for my game in Unity. That was fine and dandy, but now I'm getting stuck on a seemingly easier thing.

I am just trying to change a bunch of Booleans/integers by loading it through a JSON file, so players hosting their own server can customize it to their own style.

Here is my old way which worked fine. The ..... is just repetitive code I took out.

```
     void SetInitialReferences()
            {
                itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Items.json"));
                ConstructItemDatabase();
            }

            public Item FetchItemByID(int id)
            {
                for( int i = 0; i < dataBase.Count; i++  )          
                    if (dataBase[i].ItemID == id)
                        return dataBase[i];           
                return null;
            }
    void ConstructItemDatabase()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < itemData.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataBase.Add(new Item((int)itemData[i]["id"], ...........));
                }
            }

  public class Item
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
..........

 public Item (int itemId...............)
        {
            this.ItemID = itemId;
............
}
```

Now here is my new code, I don't want to put it in a list, because I don't need to access it more than once.

```
 void Start()
        {
            serverData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/ServerData.json"));
            ChangeServerOptions();
        }



        public void ChangeServerOptions()
        {

            this.treesRespawn = (bool)serverData["TreesRespawn"];
            this.rocksRespawn = (bool)serverData["RocksRespawn"];
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

And finally here's my error, I think Its because I'm using JsonMapper.ToObject, but I don't know any other way.

```
InvalidOperationException: Instance of JsonData is not a dictionary
LitJson.JsonData.EnsureDictionary ()
LitJson.JsonData.get_Item (System.String prop_name)
Overdose.GameManager_ServerOptions.ChangeServerOptions () (at Assets/Scripts/MasterScripts/GameManager_ServerOptions.cs:61)
Overdose.GameManager_ServerOptions.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/MasterScripts/GameManager_ServerOptions.cs:53)
```

I just need to allow people who aren't coders to change settings in their server.

Here's the old JSON:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "G36c",
    "description": "Primary Weapon. Automatic Rifle, uses 5.56 ammuntion.",
    "value": 50000,
  "maxQuantity": 1,
  "maxSpecialQuantity" :  1,
    "health": 100,
  "type": "Weapon",
  "secondType": "",
  "specialType": "PrimaryWeapon",
  "attachments": 6,
  "smuggle": false,
  "ammoType": "FiveAmmo",
  "battery": false,
  "fuel" :  false,
      "stackable": false,
    "slug": "g36c"
  },
```

and new:

```
   {
        //Resources
        "TreesRespawn": true,
        "RocksRespawn": true,
        "MiscResourceRespawn": true,
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
syncSystemDate = (bool)serverData[0]["SyncSystemData"];
```

I didn't realize it was considered as an array, so I had to add in the [0].
This was bugging me for hours, and it seemed so simple, which it was....